# How to assign values to an array?

Tags: java, arrays

Ok, I'm trying to create a hamburger object, it has to have an array of toppings and other things. I keep getting a compilation error every time I try to assign values to the array for each object. Here's the class

```
/*
This Hamburger class is to define how to make a Hamburger sandwich
Then this class will be used to create a Hamburger object in the tester class

Fields & their purpose  
4. toppings – an array of Strings storing the toppings on the burger.

*/
public class Hamburger {

    //declear private fields
    private int weight;
    private String doneness; 
    private boolean cheese;
    private String[] toppings;

      //creat arrays for each object, then use it in each specific object
      //String[] hamburgerToppings = {"l", "m"};
      //String[] cheseburgerToppings = {"l", "m"};
      //String[] anotherCheseburgerToppings = {"l", "m"};


    //create printable array of toppings


    //full constructor 
    public Hamburger(int weightOZ, String done, 
                    boolean WantCheese, String[] topps) {     
        weight = weightOZ;
        doneness = done;
        cheese = WantCheese;
        toppings = topps;
        }

    //overloaded no-arg constructor
    public Hamburger(){

    }

    //copy constructor
    public Hamburger(Hamburger burger){     
        weight = burger.weight;
        doneness = burger.doneness;
        cheese = burger.cheese;
        toppings = burger.toppings;       
    }

    //declear getter methods
    public int getWeight() {
      return weight;
 }
    public String getDoneness() {
      return doneness;
 }
```

and here's the tester class

```
//This class will test & run the Hamburger class
//It has the main method to run the other methods in the Hamburger class
public class HamburgerTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      //Creating Hamburger objects
      Hamburger hamburger = new Hamburger();
      Hamburger cheseburger = new Hamburger();
      Hamburger anotherCheseburger = new Hamburger(cheseburger);

      //Setting Values for hamburger object
      hamburger.setWeight(7);
      hamburger.setDoneness("Mediuem Rare");
      hamburger.setCheese(false);
      hamburger.setToppings();

      //Setting Values for cheseburger object
      cheseburger.setWeight(10);
      cheseburger.setDoneness("Well Done");
      cheseburger.setCheese(true);
      //cheseburger.setToppings();

      //anotherCheseburger object is a copy of cheseburger
      //there's no need to set special values for it

      //Printing Results
      System.out.println("Hamburger weight is: " + hamburger.getWeight() + 
                         " doneness: " + hamburger.getDoneness() +
                         " with/without cheese: " + hamburger.getCheese() + 
                         " Toppings: " + hamburger.getToppings());   

      System.out.println("cheseburger: " + cheseburger.toString());
      System.out.println("cheseburger copy: " + anotherCheseburger.toString());
      System.out.println("cheseburger wieght after a bite: " + cheseburger.bite());
      System.out.println("cheseburger wieght after a 2 bites: " + cheseburger.bite());        
    }
}

    public boolean getCheese() {
      return cheese;
 }
    public String[] getToppings() {
      return toppings;
 }


    //declear setter methods
    public void setWeight(int weightOZ) {
        this.weight = weightOZ;
 }
    public void setDoneness(String done) {
        this.doneness = done;
 }
    public void setCheese(boolean WantCheese) {
        this.cheese = WantCheese;
 }
    public void setToppings(String[] topps) {
        this.toppings = topps;        
      for(int i =0; i < toppings.length; i++) {
        if (i > 0) 
          System.out.print(", ");        
        System.out.print(toppings[i]);
      }
 }


   //copy method
   public Hamburger copy(){
     Hamburger burger = new Hamburger(weight, doneness, cheese, toppings);
     return burger;     
   }

    //bite methode 
    public int bite(){
        if (weight > 0) 
            weight--;    
        return weight;
    }

    //toString method to print what each Hamburger contains 
    public String toString(){

     String str = "Weight is: " + weight +
                  "\nDoneness is: " + doneness +
                  "\nCheese is: " + cheese + 
                  "\nToppings are: " + toppings;             
       return str; 
   }
}
```

any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Would be helpful to know the compile error.

Comment: File: C:\Users\khale\Desktop\Assingment 2 progress\HamburgerTester.java  [line: 22]
Error: method setToppings in class Hamburger cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.lang.String[]
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Answer (score -1):

Ill try to help, What Are you trying to do? Your getter and setter methods for the object Hamburger appear to be in the class Hamburgertester.

Comment: I'm calling the setter and getter in the tester class, I'm trying to set toppings to something alongside {"l", "t", "m"} in this line in the tester class
      hamburger.setToppings();

Comment: This is not an answer. You should put it as a comment.

Comment: oops sorry, new to replying.